# How to die in space?

Tags: karoshi-2

On the space level of [Karoshi 2](http://www.addictinggames.com/karoshisuicide2.html), how can I kill myself? There are three planets and a bit of text `What is this?`

Comment: ah.  You have to `<spoiler> <spoiler>`

Comment: For the record, Karoshi is a game where the point is to kill yourself in each level.  This IS in fact a real question.

Comment: Since Karoshi is in fact a free flash game, a [link](http://www.addictinggames.com/karoshisuicide2.html) seems in order.

Comment: Nice try, but not quite up to the Dwarf Fortress standard of strange question titles.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's been a while since I played it but that level sounds familiar, let me see...

So, you're in space.  And it says "What is this"...
Have you tried pressing the *Space* bar?

:P

Comment: lol.  Hence my `<spoiler> <spoiler>` comment

Comment: Whoops.  My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Just press the "space bar" and hit that darn spaceship :P